# How to calculate conversion rate in EXCEL POWER PIVOT

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerpivot

How should I go about creating a conversion rate(Win Rate) field? I haven't been able to figure out a way to do so for the entire datasheet rather than per specific 'ID'.

This is important because I plan to add slicers to further filter my data.

I've attached a photo of how I would need the data to be calculated.

[image]

Comment: That looks like a simple division of the total using GETPIVOTDATA formulas to me, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Thank you, you've lead me in the right direction! Had no clue about getpivotdata